# Maximum value from dictionary using python

Tags: python

```
s={'a': [11, 22, 33], 'b': [44, 77, 99], 'c': [99, 200, 100]}
```

Output should be the maximum value from each dictionary like `a=33, b=99, c=200`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple comprehension:

```
>>> {k: max(v) for k, v in s.items()}
{'a': 33, 'b': 99, 'c': 200}
```